# So maybe I got the wrong printer?

Tags: color, print-production, color-reproduction, digital-printing

Here I am again with my printing issues. So I found this old business card printed on uncoated paper: 
[image]

Since I am having problems in printing bright colors on matte coated paper with my IP8750, I wonder how come this guy get this level of brightness on uncoated paper. Maybe I should switch to a different kind of printer? If so, which one?

Comment: That looks like a raised thermographic (faux) "engraving" using glossy powdered ink. Matte finish is also available. If the image is slightly raised and can be scratched off, it is symptomatic of the process. Printers that can do this are not a trivial hardware expense.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stan. I was thinking if laser printing could give me a similar result with less investment, or if in general which one is a good multitasking printer to achieve good results as a small graphic studio

Comment: You can do a small run by getting some of the powdered ink and sprinkling some on wet ink to adhere it to the piece. Blow off the excess. Then, all you do is put it into a toaster oven to let it puff-up, and let it cool to fix.

Comment: @ Stefano Pesce A laser printer would be a lot closer with less investment. I've gotten some pretty good results from a laser printer. It gives a smooth feeling when you touch it. It's nicer than regular ink. I think it is a little brighter too. At least from my experience with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't print 'bright' colors on uncoated stock on a desktop inkjet printer because the uncoated stock just soaks in the ink.

Your sample card appears to be printed offset. Possibly using opaque inks, raised ink, a varnish, or some combination of those techniques.

Comment: Looking around the web for offset printing process, I saw that is best suited for large quantities and that big part of the process is in the setup step. But this business card has been printed as a test (so it was a single unit) and with no visible setup. Is it still possible that is offset printing?

Comment: @StefanoPesce that is correct. Offset printing is essentially commercial printing on printing presses. If that's a one-off printing, you really need to ask whoever printed it. It could be a desktop wax printer. Maybe it's using laser-printer compatible foil, perhaps it's screen printed. It's really hard to say how they did it. But they likely didn't use a desktop ink jet if that is uncoated paper.

Comment: do you think is possible they are using something like this? I seem to read they are not offset https://www.canon.it/business-printers-and-faxes/cut-sheet-colour-printers/

Comment: @StefanoPesce sure, it's possible, though those aren't really meant for 'single printed sheet of paper' either. Those are for full production runs.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to tell for sure from a photograph, but that looks like offset lithographic printing and thermography. Basically, after printing and while the ink is still wet, the sheets are run through a machine that coats the entire sheet with powdered resin. The powdered resin sticks to the wet ink and the excess is removed by suction from the unprinted areas. The sheet then goes through a heating unit that melts resin.

It won't work with inkjet printing, since the process relies on wet litho ink for the resin to stick to it. Inkjet ink dries almost instantly.

Offset litho press with thermography unit attached, and example below.

[[image: Offset litho press with thermography unit attached[1]]

[image: Offset thermography example]